# How to Run a Live Website on both side, using Microsoft Live Share while collaborating on vs code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, next.js, vscode-liveshare

How to Run a Live Website on both side, using Microsoft Live Share while collaborating on vs code?

I'm collaborating with my friends for a website project. While we are able to share code with Microsoft Live Share on VS Code.

We're unable to run the live website on both our computers.

As I'm hosting the code, when I run

```
npm run dev
```

Or any other such command, I can see the live website, while my collaborators can not.

What should we do, so that all the collaborators can view the live website?